# How can I know the correct timing for a custom display resolution?

Tags: display, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, timing, lg-monitor

After installing the latest version of Windows 10, somehow Nvidia and Windows don't longer offer the 1080p standard resolution for my display, when it did wonderfully without a trouble before.

I noticed that I can set a custom resolution and it kind of works. I worry braking it because I don't know anything about timing. To make it work I have to select different timings that I don't know which work better with my display.

I have this monitor: http://www.lg.com/us/support-product/lg-IPS225T-BN
And a Dell laptop with this card: Nvidia 8400M GS.

How can I determinate the correct timing for 1920x1080?

[image: Screenshot showing the timing setting in the Nvidia control panel]

Comment: @Seth By observing the Nvidia control panel, I assume it's more than just refresh rate...

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/y2m9T

Comment: By installing the appropriate drivers for oyur display you might get it to be not recognized as an Analog Display which might help things. As your screenshot shows there is an automatic setting. It's probably save to use it.

Comment: @Seth though it doesn't work at all with the standard set in "Automatic", other options "kind of" work... But, I'm pretty sure I could brake my display if I don't choose the right standard. There's also an Manual option, where you can set yourself the whole thing. It seems to my personal expertise, that this is very complicated.

Comment: Well in order to figure out what to set manually you would need to check the technical specification of that display. It's unlikely that it will contain that information (for consumer level information) so you might have to contact the vendor. But honestly it sounds like something broke with your setup. Reinstalling Nvidia Drivers, reattaching the display and making sure that appropriate drivers (if available) for that display are installed are likely better options. Also using DVI or HDMI instead of a D-Sub connection might improve the situation if possible.